# Usando função para fazer um subset e plotar com somente 1 comando (R)

Tags: r, data.frame, funções, plot

Meu dataFrame chama `EWMA_SD252` 3561 obs. of 102 variables (volatilidades diarias de 100 ações desde 2000), segue um sample :

```r
     Data       IBOV     ABEV3    AEDU3    ALLL3
3000 2012-02-09 16.88756 15.00696 33.46089 25.04788
3001 2012-02-10 18.72925 14.55346 32.72209 24.93913
3002 2012-02-13 20.87183 15.25370 31.91537 24.28962
3003 2012-02-14 20.60184 14.86653 31.04094 28.18687
3004 2012-02-15 20.07140 14.56653 37.45965 33.47379
3005 2012-02-16 19.99611 16.80995 37.36497 32.46208
3006 2012-02-17 19.39035 17.31730 38.85145 31.50452
```

O que eu estou tentando fazer é utilizando somente 1 comando, criar um novo dataframe somente de um intervalo entre 2 datas de uma ação escolhida e automaticamente plotar o grafico dessde intervalo, o que eu fiz ate agora foi :

Escolhendo o Intervalo de Datas e a ação :

```r
    datas = function(x,y,z){
    intervalo_datas(as.Date(x,"%d/%m/%Y"),as.Date(y,"%d/%m/%Y"),z)
    }
```

Criando o Novo data.frame com o intervalo escolhido :

```r
 intervalo_datas <- function(x,y,z){
 cbind(as.data.frame(EWMA_SD252[,1]),as.data.frame(EWMA_SD252[,z]))[EWMA_SD252$Data >= x    & EWMA_SD252$Data <= y,]
 }
```

Agora eu não consegui avançar, gostaria de tambem plotar o grafico utilizando o comando abaixo, é possivel ?

```r
ABEV3 = datas("09/02/2012","17/02/2012","ABEV3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma função do R que vai fazer isso automaticamente, mas você pode criar uma função para isso.

Uma função que faça um gráfico automaticamente das ações em certo período seria mais ou menos assim. Vou usar os pacotes ggplot2 e reshape2, então antes você precisa instalá-los se ainda não os tiver:

```r
install.packages("ggplot2") ## instala ggplot2
install.packages("reshape2") ## instala reshape2
```

Agora a função:

```r
graficos <- function(dados, data1, data2, acoes){
  require(ggplot2)
  require(reshape2)
  data1 <- as.Date(data1, "%d/%m/%Y") ## transforma em data
  data2 <- as.Date(data2, "%d/%m/%Y") ## transforma em data
  dados <- dados[dados$Data > data1 & dados$Data < data2,c("Data", acoes)] ## filtra
  dados <- melt(dados, id="Data") ## transforma os dados para o ggplot
  names(dados) <- c("Data", "Ação", "Valor") ## renomeia as colunas
  ggplot(dados, aes(Data, Valor, color=Ação)) + geom_line() ## gráficos
}
```

Aqui você pode fazer um gráfico de linha para uma sequência de datas e um conjunto de ações. Por exemplo, de 09 a 17 de fevereiro ação ABEV3:

```r
grafico(EWMA_SD252, "09/02/2012", "17/02/2012", "ABEV3")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para o mesmo período e duas ações diferentes, ABEV3 e AEDU3:

```r
grafico(EWMA_SD252, "09/02/2012", "17/02/2012", c("ABEV3", "AEDU3"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom ! Obrigado